# How to get Products which have no attribute | Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I am using Magento2. There are many products which have no attribute `is_imported` and `is_csv_imported`. I want to get and delete all these products.

Here is my custom script:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();



$productcollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$productcollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productcollection->addAttributeToFilter('is_imported', array('neq' => 1));
$productcollection->addAttributeToFilter('is_csv_imported', array('neq' => 1));



foreach ($productcollection as $product){
    print_r($product->getId());
}

?>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: not returns products which have no these attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();



$productcollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$productcollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productcollection->addAttributeToFilter('is_imported', [['null' => true],['neq' => 1]], "left");
$productcollection->addAttributeToFilter('is_csv_imported', [['null' => true],['neq' => 1]], "left");



foreach ($productcollection as $product){
    print_r($product->getId());
}

?>
```

Always use **left join** if you filter data with **not equal** statements. Otherwise - you won't get any rows without any attribute value. Your original query was getting all products where attributes were actually **not null** **and** **not equal 1**.

Comment: returned 3k products there are also other 3k

Comment: Print the query by adding line:
`echo $productcollection->getSelect(); die;` before foreach loop.